# Javascript page stops responding after opening new window

Tags: javascript

in my Javascript code I have an infinite while loop which clicks a button, collects values from few textboxes and sends them to a PHP script. I don't know how else to do this, but open a new window for the PHP script. Everything is running on localhost. So my code looks like this:

```
 <body onload="generator();">
...
  function generator(){
  phpWindow = window.open("http://localhost/adressSaver.php", "", "width=200, height=100");
  while(true){
      document.getElementById("genRandom").click();
      var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
      var second = document.getElementById("second").value;
      phpWindow.location = "http://localhost/adressSaver.php?first=" + first + "&second=" + second;
      }
}
```

I assumed that using this, every cycle the variables would be passed to the PHP script. But instead of that, when I open this document, a new window for the PHP is created, and then both the windows keep loading forever not doing anything. I even tried to cancel the loop and make it a one-time operation, no change.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you must use `setInterval` so that execution is not blocked indefinitely by your code:

```
function generator() {
  phpWindow = window.open("http://localhost/adressSaver.php", "", "width=200, height=100");
  window.setInterval(function () {
      while(true) {
          document.getElementById("genRandom").click();
          var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
          var second = document.getElementById("second").value;
          phpWindow.location = "http://localhost/adressSaver.php?first=" + first +     "&second=" + second;
      }
}}, 10);
```

This will cause your code to be executed every 10 milliseconds which you can change to whatever you like. Changing it to 0 will cause the code to be executed without delay (although there is actually a delay since javascript is not multi-threaded).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now the main window loads fine, but the phpWindow loads and stays idle, the redirect with passing the variables doesn't work, could you help me with that please?

Comment: My mistake, 10 miliseconds was just too short, tried 100 and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because JavaScript and page rendering has only one thread. It means that while your loop is active nothing may happen: neither any other JS (like mouse click, etc) nor any DOM nodes rendering.
To fix it - simply add a "break" for your loop:

```
function generator(){
    phpWindow = window.open("http://localhost/adressSaver.php", "", "width=200, height=100");
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("genRandom").click();
        var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
        var second = document.getElementById("second").value;
        phpWindow.location = "http://localhost/adressSaver.php?first=" + first + "&second=" + second;
    }, 1000);
}
```

This will execute the code each second.